# API Gateway authenticating with sigv4 gives "message: Missing Authentication Token"

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, aws-api-gateway

I implemented sigv4 authentication on my requests to my API but I am getting { "message": "Missing Authentication Token" } as a response whenever I try to hit it. When I test out using Postman with the same host, authorization headers, content-type, access key, secret key, region, and service name, the call works. Does this mean that I am not sending the request with the headers correctly or generating the authorization headers right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are receiving `Missing Authentication Token` because you do not have valid signed cookies or query string parameters.

If you are using postman, make sure you enable cookies for the given site.

**More about Signed Cookies:**

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-cookies.html#private-content-check-expiration-cookie

**Signed Parameters:**

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-query-string-auth.html

If you receive Invalid Key Pair, it is either the time for your signed url is expired or you are not using the right key to generate those authenticated values.

**EDIT1:**

It is also a generic error from CloudFront if the content is not found.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/customize-gateway-responses.html

Hope it helps.

Comment: I am deriving the signing key with nodejs and trying to hit the endpoint directly without postman. With postman, everything works fine. So to clarify, the missing authentication token message means that I am making the request properly but am just not sending in the correct authenticated values?

Comment: Not necessarily.  This answer is not complete.  `Missing authentication token` is the generic error that API Gateway uses for many conditions, by default, including things you might assume would return 404.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/customize-gateway-responses.html

Comment: @deeformvp Your origin might not be found. You can directly test with origin to make sure the request is still valid.